# Returning only the Character_Value from exec xp_msver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the processor information from the SQL Server machine as a presentable string for a project of mine. Whenever I would write

```
exec xp_msver 'ProcessorType'
```

It currently only returns the internal_value column due to my code layout where I am requesting only one value.

How would I go about returning only the character_value aka. the actual name of the processor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the string value you need to return `Character_Value` column:

```
CREATE TABLE #SystemInfo( [Index] INT, Name NVARCHAR( 200 ), Internal_Value INT, Character_Value NVARCHAR( 300 ))
INSERT INTO #SystemInfo
exec xp_msver

SELECT *
FROM #SystemInfo
WHERE Name = 'ProcessorType'
```

On my computer it returns:

> PROCESSOR_INTEL_PENTIUM

The above does not look like a very useful piece of info.

After a few minutes of Googling I was able to find this:

```
-- Scritp to get Processor Info from Registry
EXEC xp_instance_regread
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0',
'ProcessorNameString';
```

On my computer it returns:

```
Value                  Data
ProcessorNameString    Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       M 640  @ 2.80GHz
```

Example taken from: https://sqldbpool.com/2011/10/19/script-to-get-the-cpu-and-memory-information/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For the xp_instance_regread is there a way to modify the script to only display the data column?

Comment: Use the same approach as what I have done for xp_msver: create a temp table with 2 columns and do `INSERT ... EXEC`